# Mobile Header scrolling slightly up and then fixing rather than staying fixed at top:0

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, shadcnui

Have written a custom component called MobileHeader as follows:

```
"use client";

import logo from '../../../public/logo.svg'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Drawer, DrawerClose, DrawerContent, DrawerHeader, DrawerTrigger } from '../ui/drawer'
import { HamburgerMenuIcon, Cross2Icon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Heading from './Heading';
import Content from './Content';

interface HeaderMobileProps {
    className?: string;
}

const HeaderMobile = ({ className }: HeaderMobileProps) => {
    return (
        <nav className="h-[65px] w-svw flex justify-between p-4 border-b items-center bg-background sm:hidden fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50"
        >
            <div className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center gap-x-1">
                <Image
                    src={logo}
                    alt="Logo"
                    width={45}
                    height={45}
                />
                <Link href="#"><Content size='medium' fontWeight='semi-bold'>Logo</Content></Link>
            </div>
            <Drawer>
                <DrawerTrigger>
                    <HamburgerMenuIcon className="w-6 h-6" />
                </DrawerTrigger>

                <DrawerContent className='h-[80%]'>
                    <DrawerHeader>
                        <div className="w-full flex flex-row justify-end">
                            <DrawerClose>
                                <Cross2Icon className="w-6 h-6" />
                            </DrawerClose>

                        </div>
                    </DrawerHeader>
                    <div className='flex flex-col items-start md:space-y-8 space-y-6 xs:space-y-3 sm:mt-7 xs:-mt-4 mx-4'>
                        <Link href="#features">
                            <Heading size='medium' fontWeight='medium'>
                                Features
                            </Heading>
                        </Link>
                        <Link href="#pricing">
                            <Heading size='medium' fontWeight='medium'>
                                Pricing
                            </Heading>
                        </Link>
                        <Link href="#aboutus">
                            <Heading size='medium' fontWeight='medium'>
                                About Us
                            </Heading>
                        </Link>

                    </div>
                </DrawerContent>
            </Drawer>

        </nav>
    )
}

export default HeaderMobile
```

The ShadCn UI Component I am using is Drawer, as follows:

```
"use client"

import * as React from "react"
import { Drawer as DrawerPrimitive } from "vaul"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"

const Drawer = ({
  shouldScaleBackground = true,
  ...props
}: React.ComponentProps<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Root>) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Root
    shouldScaleBackground={shouldScaleBackground}
    {...props}
  />
)
Drawer.displayName = "Drawer"

const DrawerTrigger = DrawerPrimitive.Trigger

const DrawerPortal = DrawerPrimitive.Portal

const DrawerClose = DrawerPrimitive.Close

const DrawerOverlay = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Overlay>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Overlay>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Overlay
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("fixed h-[80%] inset-0 z-50 bg-black/80 dark:bg-muted", className)}
    {...props}
  />
))
DrawerOverlay.displayName = DrawerPrimitive.Overlay.displayName

const DrawerContent = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Content>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Content>
>(({ className, children, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPortal>
    <DrawerOverlay />
    <DrawerPrimitive.Content
      ref={ref}
      className={cn(
        "fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 z-50 mt-24 flex h-auto flex-col rounded-t-[10px] border bg-background",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    >
      <div className="mx-auto mt-4 h-2 w-[100px] rounded-full bg-muted" />
      {children}
    </DrawerPrimitive.Content>
  </DrawerPortal>
))
DrawerContent.displayName = "DrawerContent"

const DrawerHeader = ({
  className,
  ...props
}: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => (
  <div
    className={cn("grid gap-1.5 p-4 text-center sm:text-left", className)}
    {...props}
  />
)
DrawerHeader.displayName = "DrawerHeader"

const DrawerFooter = ({
  className,
  ...props
}: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => (
  <div
    className={cn("mt-auto flex flex-col gap-2 p-4", className)}
    {...props}
  />
)
DrawerFooter.displayName = "DrawerFooter"

const DrawerTitle = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Title>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Title>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Title
    ref={ref}
    className={cn(
      "text-lg font-semibold leading-none tracking-tight",
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  />
))
DrawerTitle.displayName = DrawerPrimitive.Title.displayName

const DrawerDescription = React.forwardRef<
  React.ElementRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Description>,
  React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof DrawerPrimitive.Description>
>(({ className, ...props }, ref) => (
  <DrawerPrimitive.Description
    ref={ref}
    className={cn("text-sm text-muted-foreground", className)}
    {...props}
  />
))
DrawerDescription.displayName = DrawerPrimitive.Description.displayName

export {
  Drawer,
  DrawerPortal,
  DrawerOverlay,
  DrawerTrigger,
  DrawerClose,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerFooter,
  DrawerTitle,
  DrawerDescription,
}
```

Issue is as follows:

1. On Page Load:
   [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCGAj.png)
2. On Page Scroll on Y Axis:
   [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyZeC.png)

Unable to understand why this is happening. Mobile header resides in my layout.tsx as follows:

```
 <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body className={cn("overscroll-y-none", outfit.className)}>

        <ThemeProvider
          attribute="class"
          defaultTheme="system"
          enableSystem
          disableTransitionOnChange
        >
          <HeaderDesktop />
          <HeaderMobile />
          {/* <BackLine /> */}
          {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
```

1. Tried overscroll-y-none in body
2. Multiple heights and padding on mobile header
3. Tried relocating header to different sections
4. Tried border-box, padding, margin as 0 for * in global.css